# Button Image Icon Not Showing

Tags: java

Take note that I am a newbie.

In my programming book "SamTeachYourself Java (in 24 hrs) 7th edition", it says on page 252 (just in case if anyone has it with them right now) that you can add an image icon on a button by doing what I did on line 7, 8 and 9. When I ran the program, the buttons showed up, without the picture. For some reason, before I added the icon, I had text on the button. When I ran with the icons, the text was still on the button, even when I removed the text for the icons. I need serious help!

```
package thing;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Thing extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("Desktop\\oof.png");
    JButton fireTorpedos = new JButton(a);
    JButton noTorpedos = new JButton(a);
    JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
    JLabel txt = new JLabel("Sir, should we fire the torpedos?");
    JLabel output = new JLabel("");
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String cmd = event.getActionCommand();
        switch(cmd) {
           case "1":

               noTorpedos.setEnabled(false);
               output.setText("You fired the torpedos!");
               break;
           case "2":

               fireTorpedos.setEnabled(false);
               output.setText("You refuse to fire the torpedos!");
               break;
           case "3":

               fireTorpedos.setEnabled(true);
               noTorpedos.setEnabled(true);
               output.setText("You reset the program.");
               break;

        }
  }
    public Thing() {
        super("Torpedo Launcher!!");
        setLookAndFeel();
        setSize(200, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel grid = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout box = new BoxLayout(grid, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        grid.setLayout(box);
        setVisible(true);
        FlowLayout foo = new FlowLayout();
        fireTorpedos.addActionListener(this);
        noTorpedos.addActionListener(this);
        reset.addActionListener(this);
        fireTorpedos.setActionCommand("1");
        noTorpedos.setActionCommand("2");
        reset.setActionCommand("3");
        grid.add(fireTorpedos);
        grid.add(noTorpedos);
        grid.add(reset);
        grid.add(txt);
        grid.add(output);
        add(grid);





    }
    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel (
                    "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel"
            );
        } catch (Exception exc) {

    }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thing frame = new Thing();
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe set a full location of the image file. If you are using Windows, it should be `C:\\Users\\(user)\\Desktop\\oof.png`. Also, I’d like to note that most books with titles like “Learn <programming language> in <x seconds/minutes/days/months/years>” are usually not a good information source.

Comment: I tried that, but it never worked!

Comment: Never mind, it worked!